# Getting value from JSON response

Tags: java, android, json, okhttp

What I need to accomplish is simple - I used OKHttp to get a JSON encoded response from my server, and I need to parse a simple (one dimensional) JSON response to extract a single value.

I've written a simple code snippet, but I'm getting an error.

Here's the code for OKHttpClient in case it matters:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
RequestBody formVars = new FormBody.Builder().add(..vars..).build();
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).post(formVars).build();
Response response = null;
try {
      response = client.newCall(request).execute();
      JSONObject jj = new JSONObject((Map) response.body());
      String e = jj.getString("status");
} catch {
      ...
}
```

The error I'm getting (red line) is under `jj.getString("status");`:

`Unhandled exception: org.json.JSONException`

The JSON string is simply
`{"status":"1"}`

Comment: Your catch clause doesn't have any exception in it... Android Studio can auto complete that for you

Answer (score 4):

You have forgotten to convert that response to string. All you need to do is following:

```
String stringResponse = response.body().string();

JSONObject jj = new JSONObject(stringResponse);
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. While you are correct, please see my comment above

Comment: Yes i think I misunderstood .I only saw that string conversion. Unhandled exception arrives because of undefined catch clause.

Answer (score 0):

> throws JSONException

add the above line to your method. and convert your response to String.

```
JSONObject objJsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());
System.out.println(objJsonObject.getString("status"));
```

also your catch block is wrong. if throws is not correct here then this would be the correct declaration. of try and catch block. add finally if required.

```
try {

} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your catch clause to catch the exception like this:

```
try {
      response = client.newCall(request).execute();
      JSONObject jj = new JSONObject((Map) response.body());
      String e = jj.getString("status");
} catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Unhandled exception: org.json.JSONException

Clearly states that you are not handling this checked exception, This is how you catch exceptions.

```
try {
....
} catch (JSONException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```